# Custom DatePicker in .NET MAUI

Tags: c#, .net, maui, maui-windows

I'm trying to build a custom datePicker in .NET MAUI but I have some issue to solve.
First of all this is how the DatePicker should be:

[image]

The main problem is that I would like clicking above the label "Pick a date" to open the calendar for date selection. So, in other words, I would like to trigger a fake click of the datePicker control by clicking on the label.
This is the xaml code of my custom control:

```
<Grid xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="myProject.Custom_controls.CustomDatePicker"
             RowDefinitions="50"
             x:Name="this" >

    <!-- External rounded border -->
    <Border x:Name="borderDatePickerCustom" Grid.Row="0" Padding="8" StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 10,10,10,10" Stroke="{Binding Source = {x:Reference this}, Path = BorderColor}" 
            StrokeThickness="1">
        <Grid>

            <!-- DatePicker control -->
            <DatePicker x:Name="DatePickerCustom"
               Grid.Row="0"
               Margin="40,0,0,0"
               Format="{}{MM/dd/yyyy}"
               IsVisible="true"
               DateSelected="_OnDateSelected"
               Unfocused="_DatePickerUnfocused"/>

            <!-- Image control used to insert an icon left to the label -->
            <Image x:Name="DatePickerIcon"
            Grid.Row="0"
            VerticalOptions="Center"
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            Margin="4"
            Source="calendar.png"
            IsVisible="true" />

        </Grid>
    </Border>

    <!-- Label used like placeholder -->
    <Label x:Name="lblPlaceholder"
           IsVisible="true"
           Grid.Row="0"
           FontSize="15"
           InputTransparent="true"
           Margin="50,0,10,0"
           Text="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=Text}"
           HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand"
           VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
           TextColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=PlaceholderTextColor}"
           BackgroundColor="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=PlaceholderBackgroundColor}"
           IsEnabled="{Binding Source={x:Reference this}, Path=IsEnabledCustom}">
    </Label>

    <!-- ImageButton used to erase datePicker content -->
    <ImageButton x:Name="EraseBtn"
                 Grid.Row="0"
                 VerticalOptions="CenterAndExpand"
                 HorizontalOptions="End"
                 Source="cross.png"
                 Margin="18"
                 IsVisible="false"
                 Clicked="_EraseDatePickerBtnClick" />
</Grid>
```

Does anyone know a method that could help me? This app should work mainly on Windows platform.

The second issue is that i try to remove the calendar glyph from the datePicker control but without success

I tried in code behind to set `inputTransparent = true` to the Label but it didn't work. I also tried to trigger the `datePicker.Focus()` but also this didn't work.
I have no other ideas, I see that on Android exist PerformClick() but i'm on Windows platform.

Comment: you can attach a `TapGestureRecognizer` to any element, including the entire `Grid` or `Border`

Comment: @Jason Yes, but then what I should do? With `DatePicker.Focus()` nothing happens

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=%5Bmaui%5D+datepicker+focus+site%253Astackoverflow.com

Comment: thanks @Jason, I solved in another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To solve my problem without using the `Focus()` method, I simply set the `Opacity = 0` for the `DatePicker` and the label `ZIndex = -1` so that clicking on the label opens the flyout of the `DatePicker`. Waiting for the bug to be fixed.